# Python Discord Bot - VPS Reboot Behaviors?

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord.py, vps, python-datetime

With a friend of mine we created a simple discord bot in python, first let me explain how it works :

We created 366 different usernames, one for each day of the year. Each day at 0:01AM the bot should automatically post a message with :

- Current date (day, month, year) and the username we associated with it
- The bot should also rename its own username with the username of the day

Here is the code we made :

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from datetime import datetime
load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()
channel = client.get_channel(CHANNELID)

bissextileSpec = datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d') # To handle bissextile years

nickFile = open("nicknames.txt", "r")
nickList = nickFile.readlines()
dayNumber = datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday

# We also made special dates

if bissextileSpec == '06-01' :
    nickOfTheDay = 'SpecialNick1'
elif bissextileSpec == '07-14' :
    nickOfTheDay = 'SpecialNick2'
elif bissextileSpec == '30-12' :
    nickOfTheDay = 'SpecialNick3'
elif bissextileSpec == '17-06' :
    nickOfTheDay = 'SpecialNick4'
elif bissextileSpec == '05-04' :
    nickOfTheDay = 'SpecialNick5'
else :
    nickOfTheDay = nickList[dayNumber - 1]

await channel.send('MSG CONTENT', nickOfTheDay, 'MSG CONTENT')
await client.user.edit(username=nickOfTheDay)
```

We know our way a bit around python but we don't really know how discord bots works :

We are not quite sure how to instruct it to auto-post at midnight each day : We thought of a While loop with a sleep(50) on its end BUT :
**How is it going to handle the hazardous VPS reboots ?** If the vps reboot mid sleep is it going to reset it and shift the next post time further than 0:00 ?

**On the other end, if we don't use a While loop, but if we use the CRON system in Linux to check and start the script everyday at midnight, does it mean the bot will be shown offline 23h59/24 on Discord and stay online just to post the message ?** => We want to add a few more features later so we need the bot to run 24/24

Aswell, do not hesitate to point it if we did something wrong in the code ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Łukasz's code has a tiny flaw, the future variable is wrongly initialized but everything else is working accordingly! This should do the trick:

```
import asyncio
from discord.ext import tasks
from datetime import datetime

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def change_nickname(guild):
    nick = ""
    await guild.me.edit(nick=nick)

@change_nickname.before_loop
async def before_change_nickname():
    hour, minute = 0, 0
    now = datetime.now()
    future = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, hour, minute)
    delta = (future - now).seconds
    await asyncio.sleep(delta)
```

Comment: You could simply edit my answer or leave a comment

Answer (score 1):

You can make a loop that iterates every 24h and change the nickname of the bot, you can get the seconds till midnight with some simple math and sleep for those seconds

```py
import asyncio
from discord.ext import tasks
from datetime import datetime

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def change_nickname(guild):
    """Loops every 24 hours and changes the bots nick"""
    nick = "" # Get the nick of the corresponding day
    await guild.me.edit(nick=nick)


@change_nickname.before_loop
async def before_change_nickname(guild):
    """Delays the `change_nickname` loop to start at 00:00"""
    hour, minute = 0, 0
    
    now = datetime.now()
    future = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, now.month, now.day, hour, minute)

    delta = (future - now).seconds
    await asyncio.sleep(delta)
```

To start it you need to pass a `discord.Guild` instance (the main guild where the nickname should be changed)

```py
change_nickname.start(guild) # You can start it in the `on_ready` event or some command or in the global scope, don't forget to pass the guild instance
```

No matter what hour the bot started the loop will change the bots nick at 00:00 everyday

#### Reference:

- [`tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.loop)
- [`Loop.before_loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.before_loop)
- [`Loop.start`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.start)

Comment: thanks for the answer, so in this case if the VPS where the bot is hosted crash at 2:00AM  and reboot it won't mess anything ?

Comment: Exactly, doesn't matter at what hour the bot starts/restarts, the loop will always be delayed no matter what till 00:00